# New Dot Net application for in-house use

Tags: .net

We want to replace an old application written in a different tech by putting it together in Dot Net. The current application is a desktop app running against Windows. The new app doesn't have to be a windows app. It can be a web app run on the intranet.

The preference is to write it up in Dot Net Core 3.1+ WinForms. WinForms is easy to put together. However, are we serving the organisation's interests by going down this path or should we go with WPF or ASP.Net.

Also, Core's designer for WinForms is not available except in beta. So if we chose WinForms, it would have to be on Framework and not Core.

What is your advise? We see this application having a 5 to 10 years of life.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go down the path of creating a web application I would recommend using ASP.Net MVC web application. It supports both .net core and .net framework. The learning curve for asp.net MVC web applications is fairly low as well. There are plenty of free tutorials online and plenty of support overall for it. Visual Studio also provides some easy to understand templates right off the back for your MVC web app. Can have a debugged running web app running in minutes!

If you want to create a desktop application I would recommend using WPF. It has a much larger learning curve though. WPF is used only for creating windows desktop applications but it does also support .net core 3.0 +.

Winforms is an old technology and I would stay away from it as support for it is going away.